# Why is the value of this line integral constant

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the line integral given by $$\int_C \frac{(x+y)\,dx-(x-y)\,dy}{x^2+y^2}$$ where $C$ is any simple closed curve around the origin. Can someone explain, without using complex analysis, why this is always $-2 \pi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form $$\omega = \frac{(x+y)\,dx - (x-y)\,dy}{x^2+y^2}$$ is closed. Stokes' theorem asserts

$$\int_{\partial V} \omega = \int_V d\omega$$

for every bounded open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ with sufficiently smooth boundary, so

$$\int_C \omega = \int_{x^2+y^2 = \varepsilon} \omega$$

if we choose $\varepsilon$ so small that $C$ is entirely outside the disk $x^2+y^2 \leqslant \varepsilon$, since then the two curves - with proper orientation - make up the boundary of a region that is topologically an annulus.

Comment: if $\omega$ would be closed the $d\omega=0$ right?

Comment: Right, that's the definition of closed.

Comment: then $\int_Vd\omega=0$?

Comment: Yes, $\int_V d\omega = \int_V 0 = 0$.

Comment: this contradicts $\int_{\partial V}\omega\neq0$, right?

Comment: But $\int_{\partial V} \omega = 0$ is the result that says that the integral is independent of the curve (subject to the restriction that it winds once around the origin). The two curves $C$ and $\varepsilon(\cos \varphi, \sin\varphi)$ _together_ bound the region $V$, one positively oriented, one negatively, so the integrals cancel. Note that $\omega$ is not defined, let alone differentiable in the origin, so $V$ must not contain the origin in Stokes' theorem.

Comment: Before that you just explain, in your answer you'd said $\int_{\partial V}\omega=\int_Vd\omega$...

Comment: ok, ok i got it... (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Do a parametrization of your curve
$$
x(t) = r(t) \cos t \\
y(t) = r(t) \sin t
$$
then 
\begin{align}
dx &= (r'\cos t - r\sin t) dt \\
dy &= (r'\sin t + r\cos t) dt
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
I &= \int_C \frac {(x+y)dx - (x-y)dy}{x^2+y^2} = \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {r(\cos t + \sin t)(r'\cos t - r\sin t) dt - r(\cos t - \sin t)(r'\sin t + r\cos t) dt}{r^2} = \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {r'-r}r dt = \int_0^{2\pi} d(\ln r) - \int_0^{2\pi} dt = \left . \ln r \right|_{0}^{2\pi} - 2\pi = r(2\pi) - r(0) - 2\pi = -2\pi
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\cal I}
     \equiv
     \int_{C}{\pars{x + y}\,\dd x - \pars{x - y}\,\dd y \over x^{2} + y^{2}}
      = -2\pi:\ {\large ?}}.\quad$
With
$\ds{r \equiv \root{x^{2} + y^{2}}\,,\quad\nabla\ln\pars{r} = {\vec{r} \over r^{2}}}$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}&=\int_{C}\pars{{x + y \over r^{2}},{y - x \over r^{2}}}\cdot\dd\vec{r}
> =\int_{C}\pars{%
> \partiald{\ln\pars{r}}{x} + \partiald{\ln\pars{r}}{y},
> \partiald{\ln\pars{r}}{y} - \partiald{\ln\pars{r}}{x}}\cdot\dd\vec{r}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{S}\braces{%
> \partiald{}{x}\bracks{\partiald{\ln\pars{r}}{y} - \partiald{\ln\pars{r}}{x}}
> -
> \partiald{}{y}\bracks{\partiald{\ln\pars{r}}{x} + \partiald{\ln\pars{r}}{y}}}\,\dd S
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\,\,\,\,\overbrace{\int_{S}\nabla^{2}\ln\pars{r}\,\dd S}^{\ds{=\ 2\pi}}\tag{1}
> =\color{#00f}{\Large -2\pi}
> \end{align}

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/615984/85343), we show a derivation of $\nabla^{2}\ln\pars{r} = 2\pi\,\delta\pars{\vec{r}}$ which, indeed, is a well known result.